# Resampling a dataframe into a new one while doing some additional operations

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with a dataframe where each entry (row) comes with a start time, a duration and other attributes. I would like to create a new dataframe from this one where I would sort of transform each entry from the original one into 15 minutes intervals while keeping all other attributes the same. The amount of entries in the new dataframe per entry in the old one would depend on the actual duration of the original one.

At first I tried using pd.resample but it did not do exactly what I expected. I then constructed a function using `itertuples()` that works quite well but it took about half an hour with a dataframe of around 3000 rows. Now I want to do the same for 2 million rows so I am looking for other possibilities.

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
testdict = {'start':['2018-01-05 11:48:00', '2018-05-04 09:05:00', '2018-08-09 07:15:00', '2018-09-27 15:00:00'], 'duration':[22,8,35,2], 'Attribute_A':['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm'], 'id': [1,2,3,4]}
testdf = pd.DataFrame(testdict)
testdf.loc[:,['start']] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['start'])
print(testdf)

>>>testdf
                 start  duration Attribute_A  id
0  2018-01-05 11:48:00        22         abc   1
1  2018-05-04 09:05:00         8         def   2
2  2018-08-09 07:15:00        35         hij   3
3  2018-09-27 15:00:00         2         klm   4
```

And I would like my outcome to be like the following:

```
>>>resultdf
                start  duration Attribute_A  id
0 2018-01-05 11:45:00        12         abc   1
1 2018-01-05 12:00:00        10         abc   1
2 2018-05-04 09:00:00         8         def   2
3 2018-08-09 07:15:00        15         hij   3
4 2018-08-09 07:30:00        15         hij   3
5 2018-08-09 07:45:00         5         hij   3
6 2018-09-27 15:00:00         2         klm   4
```

This is the function that I built with itertuples which produced the desired result (the one I showed just above this):

```
def min15_divider(df,newdf):
for row in df.itertuples():
    orig_min = row.start.minute
    remains = orig_min % 15 # Check if it is already a multiple of 15
    if remains == 0:
        new_time = row.start.replace(second=0)
        if row.duration < 15: # if it shorter than 15 min just use that for the duration
            to_append = {'start': new_time, 'Attribute_A': row.Attribute_A,
                         'duration': row.duration, 'id':row.id}
            newdf = newdf.append(to_append, ignore_index=True)
        else: # if not, divide that in 15 min intervals until duration is exceeded
            cumu_dur = 15
            while cumu_dur < row.duration:
                to_append = {'start': new_time, 'Attribute_A': row.Attribute_A, 'id':row.id}
                if cumu_dur < 15:
                    to_append['duration'] = cumu_dur
                else:
                    to_append['duration'] = 15
                new_time = new_time + pd.Timedelta('15 minutes')
                cumu_dur = cumu_dur + 15
                newdf = newdf.append(to_append, ignore_index=True)

            else: # add the remainder in the last 15 min interval
                final_dur = row.duration - (cumu_dur - 15)
                to_append = {'start': new_time, 'Attribute_A': row.Attribute_A,'duration': final_dur, 'id':row.id}
                newdf = newdf.append(to_append, ignore_index=True)

    else: # When it is not an exact multiple of 15 min
        new_min = orig_min - remains # convert to multiple of 15
        new_time = row.start.replace(minute=new_min)
        new_time = new_time.replace(second=0)
        cumu_dur = 15 - remains # remaining minutes in the initial interval
        while cumu_dur < row.duration: # divide total in 15 min intervals until duration is exceeded
            to_append = {'start': new_time, 'Attribute_A': row.Attribute_A, 'id':row.id}
            if cumu_dur < 15:
                to_append['duration'] = cumu_dur
            else:
                to_append['duration'] = 15

            new_time = new_time + pd.Timedelta('15 minutes')
            cumu_dur = cumu_dur + 15
            newdf = newdf.append(to_append, ignore_index=True)

        else: # when we reach the last interval or the starting duration was less than the remaining minutes
            if row.duration < 15:
                final_dur = row.duration # original duration less than remaining minutes in first interval
            else:
                final_dur = row.duration - (cumu_dur - 15) # remaining duration in last interval
            to_append = {'start': new_time, 'Attribute_A': row.Attribute_A, 'duration': final_dur, 'id':row.id}
            newdf = newdf.append(to_append, ignore_index=True)
return newdf
```

Is there any other way to do this without using `itertuples` that could save me some time?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I apologize for anything that may seem a bit weird in my post as it is the first time that I have asked a question myself here in stackoverflow.

### EDIT

Many entries can have the same starting time, so `.groupby` 'start' could be problematic. There is, however, a column with unique values for each entry called simply "id".

Comment: in what case original time need to go back as in 11:48:00?

Comment: It would count as if it has started in the 11:45 time step and since it lasts longer than the remaining minutes in that interval, it would exted to the next one (12:00). That's why in the result dataframe that entry is divided into an entry with start time 11:45 (with a duration of 12 minutes) and another one with start time 12 (with a duration of the remaining 10 minutes).

Comment: Are there overlapping times? What happens if there are overlapping times?

Comment: In case of overlapping times there would be multiple entries with the same value for 'start', but they would have different values for the rest of the attributes (in this example I only showed 'Attribute_A' but there are more).

Comment: @BlueSombrero all date time values beside first 11:48:00 they are divisible by 15 minutes, or there are some more random values?

Comment: How do you build `newdf` before using your function? I would like to measure the time.

Comment: I would use `itertuples` but eventually split in multiple dataframes, and trying to resample and calculated things using groupby-apply or aggregate then merge them back together as that would be faster and more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.resample` is a good idea, but since you have only the starting time each row, you need to build the end row before you can use it.

The code below assumes that **each starting time in `'start'` column is unique**, so that `grouby` can be used in a bit unusual way, since it will extract only one row.
I use `groupby` because it will automatically regroups the dataframes produced by the custom function used by `apply`.
Note also that the column `'duration'` is converted to `timedelta` in minutes in order to better perform some math later.

```
import pandas as pd

testdict = {'start':['2018-01-05 11:48:00', '2018-05-04 09:05:00', '2018-08-09 07:15:00', '2018-09-27 15:00:00'], 'duration':[22,8,35,2], 'Attribute_A':['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm']}
testdf = pd.DataFrame(testdict)
testdf['start'] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['start'])
testdf['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(testdf['duration'], 'T')
print(testdf)

def calcduration(df, starttime):
    if len(df) == 1:
        return
    elif len(df) == 2:
        df['duration'].iloc[0] = pd.Timedelta(15, 'T') - (starttime - df.index[0])
        df['duration'].iloc[1] = df['duration'].iloc[1] - df['duration'].iloc[0]
    elif len(df) > 2:
        df['duration'].iloc[0] = pd.Timedelta(15, 'T') - (starttime - df.index[0])
        df['duration'].iloc[1:-1] = pd.Timedelta(15, 'T')
        df['duration'].iloc[-1] = df['duration'].iloc[-1] - df['duration'].iloc[:-1].sum()

def expandtime(x):
    frow = x.copy()
    frow['start'] = frow['start'] + frow['duration']
    gdf = pd.concat([x, frow], axis=0)
    gdf = gdf.set_index('start')
    resdf = gdf.resample('15T').nearest()
    calcduration(resdf, x['start'].iloc[0])
    return resdf

findf = testdf.groupby('start', as_index=False).apply(expandtime)
print(findf)
```

This code produces:

```
                      duration Attribute_A
  start                                   
0 2018-01-05 11:45:00 00:12:00         abc
  2018-01-05 12:00:00 00:10:00         abc
1 2018-05-04 09:00:00 00:08:00         def
2 2018-08-09 07:15:00 00:15:00         hij
  2018-08-09 07:30:00 00:15:00         hij
  2018-08-09 07:45:00 00:05:00         hij
3 2018-09-27 15:00:00 00:02:00         klm
```

#### A bit of explanation

`expandtime` is the first custom function. It takes a dataframe of one row (because we assume that `'start'` values are uniques), builds a second row whose `'start'` is equal to `'start'` of the first row + duration and then uses `resample` to sample it in time intervals of 15 minutes. Values of all other columns are duplicated.

`calcduration` is used to do some math on the column `'duration'` in order to calculate the correct duration of each row.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I can't believe how fast it is compared to the function that I wrote before (the one in the question itself). I only did one adjustment: since the `'start'` values were not unique, I used the `groupby()` with `'start'` and another attribute that was unique to each row. I still don't quite understand why you used `groupby()` in the first place. Could you explain it to me a little bit more so that I can, in the future, do more stuff like this one? Thank yo so much! @Valentino

Comment: The construct `groupby(colname).apply(func)` allows to apply `func` to each subset identified by `groupby`. In this particular case, the subset must be a single row. And it regroups automatically the elaborated subsets returned by all the calls to `func` into a single dataframe. It's the alternative to looping over the rows using `itertuples()` and appending the results to a `newdf`. Usually is faster because everything is done internally by pandas.

Answer (score 0):

So, starting with your df:

```
testdict = {'start':['2018-01-05 11:48:00', '2018-05-04 09:05:00', '2018-08-09 07:15:00', '2018-09-27 15:00:00'], 'duration':[22,8,35,2], 'Attribute_A':['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm']}
df = pd.DataFrame(testdict)
df.loc[:,['start']] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
print(df)
```

First calculate an ending time for each row:

```
df['dur'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='m')
df['end'] = df['start'] + df['dur']
```

Then create two new columns that hold the regular interval (15 minute) start and end dates:

```
df['start15'] = df['start'].dt.floor('15min')
df['end15'] = df['end'].dt.floor('15min')
```

At this point, the dataframe looks like:

```
  Attribute_A  duration               start      dur                 end start15               end15
0         abc        22 2018-01-05 11:48:00 00:22:00 2018-01-05 12:10:00 2018-01-05 11:45:00 2018-01-05 12:00:00  
1         def         8 2018-05-04 09:05:00 00:08:00 2018-05-04 09:13:00 2018-05-04 09:00:00 2018-05-04 09:00:00     
2         hij        35 2018-08-09 07:15:00 00:35:00 2018-08-09 07:50:00 2018-08-09 07:15:00 2018-08-09 07:45:00   
3         klm         2 2018-09-27 15:00:00 00:02:00 2018-09-27 15:02:00 2018-09-27 15:00:00 2018-09-27 15:00:00
```

The `start15` and `end15` columns combine to have the right times, but you need to merge them:

```
df = pd.melt(df, ['dur', 'start', 'Attribute_A', 'end'], ['start15', 'end15'], value_name='start15')
df = df.drop('variable', 1).drop_duplicates('start15').sort_values('start15').set_index('start15')
```

Output:

```
                         dur               start Attribute_A
start15                                                     
2018-01-05 11:45:00 00:22:00 2018-01-05 11:48:00         abc
2018-01-05 12:00:00 00:22:00 2018-01-05 11:48:00         abc
2018-05-04 09:00:00 00:08:00 2018-05-04 09:05:00         def
2018-08-09 07:15:00 00:35:00 2018-08-09 07:15:00         hij
2018-08-09 07:45:00 00:35:00 2018-08-09 07:15:00         hij
2018-09-27 15:00:00 00:02:00 2018-09-27 15:00:00         klm
```

Looking good, but the `2018-08-09 07:30:00` row is missing. Fill in this and any other missing rows with groupby and resample:

```
df = df.groupby('start').resample('15min').ffill().reset_index(0, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Get the `end15` column back, it was dropped during the melt operation earlier:

```
df['end15'] = df['end'].dt.floor('15min')
```

Then calculate the correct durations for each row. I split this into two calculations (durations that spread across multiple timesteps, and ones that don't) to keep it readable:

```
df.loc[df['start15'] != df['end15'], 'duration'] = np.minimum(df['end15'] - df['start'], pd.Timedelta('15min').to_timedelta64())
df.loc[df['start15'] == df['end15'], 'duration'] = np.minimum(df['end'] - df['end15'], df['end'] - df['start'])
```

Then just some clean-up to make it look like you wanted:

```
df['duration'] = (df['duration'].dt.seconds/60).astype(int)
print(df)
df = df[['start15', 'duration', 'Attribute_A']].copy()
```

Result:

```
              start15  duration Attribute_A
0 2018-01-05 11:45:00        12         abc
1 2018-01-05 12:00:00        10         abc
2 2018-05-04 09:00:00         8         def
3 2018-08-09 07:15:00        15         hij
4 2018-08-09 07:30:00        15         hij
5 2018-08-09 07:45:00         5         hij
6 2018-09-27 15:00:00         2         klm
```

Please note, portions of this answer were based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42871452/)